# .htaccess conflicting rules

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, conflict

Having some trouble with .htaccess and conflicting rules. 
Code below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?$ static-page.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

The pages based on static-page.php work fine but when I try going to '/home' the page loads for a while then gives me nothing. 
I believe this is because the second rule is overwriting the first one.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this corrected code:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?$ static-page.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```